# Redefine \tableofcontents to start a new page after the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

How can I properly redefine `\tableofcontents`to include a `\newpage` or `\clearpage`after the table of contents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a completly LaTeX2e solution:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\tableofcontents{\clearpage}
\makeatother
```

Or simple:

```
\let\tableofcontentsORIG\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\tableofcontentsORIG\clearpage}
```

The solution works with the standard definition of `\tableofcontents` used in `article` or `book`.

Comment: It won't work in `memoir`, though.

Answer (score 3):

You may redefine `\tableofcontents` after storing the already existing `\tableofcontents`. The new version just call the previous version and adds a `clearpage`.

A small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}%dummy text
%>>>>THIS IS THE SOLUTION>>>>>
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents%remember the definition
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
  \oldtableofcontents%use the standard toc
  \clearpage
}
%<<<<END SOLUTION
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument%create dummy text with sections
\end{document}
```