# Make tocloft insert empty page after the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft

How can I redefine the `tocloft` `\tableofcontents` to insert a new page automatically after the table of contents.

The suggestions at [Redefine \tableofcontents to start a new page after the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47639/redefine-tableofcontents-to-start-a-new-page-after-the-toc) do not work because `tocloft` probably overrides them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tocloft` documentation specifically suggests manually putting in `\clearpage`.  But you can do it automatically by adding:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@cfttocfinish{\clearpage}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. (You'll need to do the same for other lists-of as well, if needed.)