# Extra code for \tableofcontents (renew)

Tags: table-of-contents, etoolbox

I want my `\tableofcontents` command to include these two commands at the beginning: `\pagestyle{headings}` and `\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}`

I tried using the `etoolbox` package, and I came with something like this (inspired in [Redefine \tableofcontents to start a new page after the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47639/redefine-tableofcontents-to-start-a-new-page-after-the-toc)):

```
\gappto\tableofcontents{\pagestyle{headings}\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,hyperindex,hyperfigures]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{empty}} % Don't use page numbering in the frontmatter                                        
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{headings}} % Use page numbering in the mainmatter

\gappto\tableofcontents{\pagestyle{headings}\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \addchap*{Publications}
    \kant
    \addchap*{Acknowledgments}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

\mainmatter %Just dummy text to fill the TOC
    \chapter{hola}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola2}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola3}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola4}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola5}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola6}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola7}
    \section{adas}
    \section{adasdas}
    \subsection{dasdsdfasdfasdf}
    \kant
        \chapter{hola2}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola3}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola4}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola5}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola6}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola7}
    \section{adas}
    \section{adasdas}
    \subsection{dasdsdfasdfasdf}
        \chapter{hola}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola2}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola3}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola4}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola5}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola6}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola7}
    \section{adas}
    \section{adasdas}
    \subsection{dasdsdfasdfasdf}
    \kant
        \chapter{hola2}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola3}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola4}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola5}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola6}
    \kant
    \chapter{hola7}
    \section{adas}
    \section{adasdas}
    \subsection{dasdsdfasdfasdf}

\end{document}
```

If you run it you'll notice a couple of things:

1. The command `\pagestyle{headings}` seems to be semi-working in the TOC: I do get the page numbers, but I'm missing the heading on the *verso* page.
2. The pdf bookmark to the TOC actually points to the *verso* page instead of the *recto* one.

**Extrabonus**: Since I'm issuing the `\pagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of `\frontmatter`, I get all pages without headings or page numbers.  However, since I'm using a couple of `\addchap*{}`, these two pages ---since, after all, are chapter pages--- do keep their numeration.  I've been dealing with it by simply typing `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of each one, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Did you really try to modify a macro spelled `\tableofcontentes`? Posting an MWE rather than a code snippet might have revealed an issue... :-) More importantly, did you try either `\preto` and `\epreto` instead of `\gappto`? Finally, please advise if you use a package such as `tocloft` to affect the appearance of the Table of Contents.

Comment: @Mico: `\epreto` is to prefer if there is some expandable content, but I agree with you about `tocloft` or via using KOMA classes and their ability to include the TOC itself in the TOC (however, since no MWE is given, there is no information on the class etc.)

Comment: Any particular reason against using `\newcommand\mytableofcontents{\pagestyle{headings}\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}\tableofcontents}`?

Comment: Why are you doing `\appto` instead of the obvious `\preto`?

Comment: @egreg Because I'm and idiot and I have no idea what I'm doing :P hehehehehehe

Comment: @1010011010 not really, this is an interesting approach too.  As mentioned in my post, I was basing myself in another question I found, where `etoolbox` is used.

Comment: @egreg I have Herbert's solution without `etoolbox`.  Do you have one using it?

Answer (score 3):

```
\let\TOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\newpage\pagestyle{headings}\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{contents}\TOC}
```

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly. Why is not working through my `etoolbox` code?

Comment: No idea, I never used that macros from `etoolbox`